# How do I create a sliding window of 5 bits in a single byte?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte, bit-shift, sliding-window

Here is a visual of what I want to have happen [5 bit sliding window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SewJy.png)

In words, I want a sliding window of 5 bits.  I need to store a history of 5 events within a single byte.  I'm using the 5 most significant bits to do this.  The first time the event occurs I want to store that in bit 7 (most significant bit), the second time the event occurs, whether true or false, I want to store the latest event history in the 7th bit, and what was previously in bit 7 will slide over to bit 6.  This will just keep repeating indefinitely, storing the latest event in bit 7 and sliding everything to the right, but only keeping 5 events.

Here is what I've tried so far, but I think my concept is pretty far off.

Edit: The for loop is just to imitate several loops of storing the history, so won't be used later on.

```
    unsigned char byte = 0;

    bool bit7 = true;
    bool bit6 = false;
    bool bit5 = true;
    bool bit4 = true;
    bool bit3 = false;

    // Set the individual bits in the byte
    byte |= (bit7 << 7);
    byte |= (bit6 << 6);
    byte |= (bit5 << 5);
    byte |= (bit4 << 4);
    byte |= (bit3 << 3);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            byte = bit7 << 7;
        }

        if (i == 1)
        {
            byte |= bit6 << 6;
        }

        if (i == 2)
        {
            byte |= bit5 << 5;
        }

        if (i == 3)
        {
            byte |= bit4 << 4;
        }

        if (i == 4)
        {
            byte |= bit3 << 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) the `for` loop and `if` statement are not needed, and 2) it would be much simpler to put the most recent flag in bit 5 after shifting the whole byte right by 1.

Comment: Save bits 2, 1, 0 `uint8_t savedbits = byte & 0x07;`, shift right `byte /= 2`, set most significant bit: `byte = ((event != 0) << 7) | (byte & 0x7f)`, restore savedbits `byte = (byte & 0xf8) | savedbits`

Comment: Do the other three bits in the byte matter? Do you have to use bit 7 for the most recent even or can you use bit 0 and arrange the bits in the other direction? When reading the bits, what operations do you need—do you need to test individual bits, all of them, or various combinations?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I actually have to use bit 7 for the most recent just because of how we defined the byte to be packed.  When reading the bits we just want to see what the value of each bit is, so just purely reading, don't need to test them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple if I understand your task well

```
uint8_t addevent(int event, uint8_t stored)
{   
    stored >>= 1;
    stored |= (!!event) << 7;

    return stored;
}
```

Comment: @uC Programmer - So I'm trying out your code, it's almost there.  When I get to the 6th event, it keeps that event.  So I have my events in order from first to last as 101100, and what I want to see is those reversed (which your code does) and then only keep the top 5, so I should see 00110, but what I'm getting instead is 001101, so I just need to knock of that 6th (and so on) event to keep only the top 5.  What changes should I make to do that?

Comment: After adding ```stored &= 0xF8;``` after the ```stored >>= 1;``` operation it worked, thank you!